# Proof of Parseval´s Theorem

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Could someone point me to a proof of Parseval's Theorem? That is,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n\bar b_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} A(x)\bar B(x) dx$$

where $A(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_ne^ {inx}$ and similarly for $B(x)$. All the proofs I've found online deal merely with the case $A(x)=B(x)$.

Comment: Do you accept the result for $A=B$? (That's basically the completeness of the trig functions.)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, I do understand the proof for the case $A=B$ if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Then you can deduce the general formula using that and the polarisation identity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity .

Comment: For complex numbers, the polarization identity is $z\overline{w}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n|z+i^n w|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$A(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}e^{inx}$$
$$B(x)=\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}b_{m}e^{imx}$$
then for a fixed $n$ we know
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a_{n}e^{inx}\overline{B(x)}\ dx = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}a_{n}\overline{b_{m}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}e^{-imx}\ dx= 2\pi a_n\overline{b_{n}}$$
where 
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{i(n-m)x}dx=
\begin{cases}
0&,~~~~n\neq m\\
2\pi&,~~~~n=m\\
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} A(x)\overline{B(x)}\ dx=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}a_{n}e^{inx}\overline{B(x)}\ dx  =  2\pi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n\overline{b_{n}}$$

Comment: How do you get from $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_ne^{inx}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\bar b_ne^{inx}$ to $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ke^{ikx}$?

Comment: I added details to hint.